# Can we have two different icons for two different devices for same application android?

Tags: android

I want my application to show some icon on device A and some other icon on device B , based on some kind of condition like device etc. Can this be done?
    What i had done is some device with two different icons for same application. But i am not able to identify how to do this.

Comment: If both the devices have different buckets (HDPI, XHDPI) you can put different icons in both buckets and it solve you query.

Comment: do put images same name of image for different dpi folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have different icons for different screen DPI.

Use different icons in different mipmap folders according to the screen DPIs.

[image]